# Google place API: PLACES_API_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED error

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am getting this error getting autocomplete prediction API call:

```
Status{
  statusCode=PLACES_API_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED,
  resolution=null
}
```

What is that I have sufficient balance on account and also enabled the payment method.

Comment: This error message means you are calling the API too fast.

Comment: i am calling method after 5 seconds with this api actually.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late but this might helps others.

I have faced this same issue. When I check in [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) my your project I found this message "*If you are seeing "Can't load" or '9005 PLACES_API_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED' errors in your Android app, your app may be using a deprecated version of the Places SDK for Android or [iOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration).*" 
**Solution:** Find migration guides for [Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) and iOS to begin using the new Places SDKs. I have followed the instruction and everything is working fine now.